# Wofür steht "hoch" im Begriff "Hochdeutsch"?

Tags: etymology

Wie kam es zum Begriff *Hochdeutsch*? Was bedeutet(e) das Wort *hoch* in diesem Zusammenhang? Hat es etwas mit "gehoben" zu tun oder ist es als Abgrenzung zu *Niederdeutsch* zu sehen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wikipedia lists two meanings of *[Hochdeutsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochdeutsch)*:

1. The German dialects, which developed in the Southern uplands and the Alps as opposed to *Plattdeutsch* / *Niederdeutsch* which was spoken near the coast:

   > In the first usage, hoch refers to "high" in a strictly geographic sense, as "situated far above sealevel", thus in the mountainous regions surrounding the Alps.
2. and the German which is taught to foreigners:

   > In the second meaning, hoch came to mean "educated" or "cult" in an academic or social context, as opposed to the local dialects which are used in informal situations.

Comment: Ich werde nie verstehen, warum in einem Deutsch-Forum auf eine Frage, die von einem Deutsch-Muttersprachler in Deutscher Sprache gestellt wurde, und die ein Thema der Deutschen Sprache zum Inhalt hat, in einer Fremdsprache geantwortet wird.

Comment: Viele Leute sind so oft im englischsprachigen Teil des Internets unterwegs (oder auch dem großteils englischem stackexchange), so dass es Ihnen gar nicht mehr auffällt, das eine Frage auf Deutsch war oder das sie auf Englisch antworten. So ist mir dies z.B. auch beim Lesen dieser Frage/Antwort gar nicht aufgefallen bis ich den Kommentar gelesen habe. Definitiv eine interessante Sache.

Comment: I was referred here by an English language discussion in which the question about what the high/hoch signifies was said to be possibly answered--in German. My German was good enough to understand the link, but not to respond in German. My hypothesis about High (read: Upper/Ober) German is that it was once as closely related to river flow as to elevation. Let me use an analogy. Lower Egypt was north of Upper Egypt because the Nile flowed downwards toward the Mediterranean Sea. Yet the land is nearly flat. It owed its Upper designation more to being upstream than to being at a higher elevation.

Answer (score 8):

[Hochdeutsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochdeutsch) (im linguistischen Sinn) wird südlich der [Benrather Linie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benrather_Linie) Deutschlands gesprochen. Es wird als relativ "raffiniertes" Deutsch angesehen. Das heißt, "Hochdeutsch" wird im "Hochland" gesprochen.

Im Gegensatz dazu wird "Plattdeutsch" in Norddeutschland gesprochen, also im "Plattland". Man sagt deshalb auch "*Platt*-deutsch" oder "*Nieder*-deutsch".

Comment: "Hoch Deutsch ist im Süden Deutschlands gesprochen" Das halte ich für ein Gerücht.

Comment: @sepp2k: ist aber so, siehe [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochdeutsche_Dialekte)!

Comment: Siehe aber auch: [Wikipedia: Hochdeutsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochdeutsch)

Comment: @Takkat: "ist aber so" ist eine mutige Aussage - der von Dir zitierte Wikipedia-Artikel ist kein überzeugender Beleg. (Er nennt praktisch keine Quellen, und vor allem ist er über hochdeutsche _Dialekte_.) Die Frage ist doch auch, was heutzutage _gemeint_ ist, wenn "Hochdeutsch" gesagt wird. (Ich glaube gerne, dass Toms Antwort den _Ursprung_ des Wortes "Hochdeutsch" erklärt, was ja auch die Frage war, aber das wird aus der Antwort so nicht klar.)

Comment: Meta: Sollte man Toms Antwort vielleicht noch einmal auf sprachliche Richtigkeit editieren?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: siehe auch [zweite Lautverschiebung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweite_Lautverschiebung) südlich der Benrather Linie in der sich Althochdeutsch von Niederdeutsch abtrennte.

Comment: @Takkat: Ich meine aber weiterhin, dass die Formulierung "Hochdeutsch wird im Süden Deutschlands gesprochen" sehr irreführend ist. Sollte man nicht nochmals editieren, um klarzustellen, dass es um den _Ursprung_ des Wortes "Hochdeutsch" geht? Hochdeutsch wird auch im Norden Deutschlands gesprochen, und zwar sehr viel!

Comment: Was genau ist hier eigentlich mit "raffiniert" gemeint? (Anm: bin selbst kein Linguist - stammt der Begriff daher?)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Es ist nicht nach der Bedeutung, sondern nach der Herkunft von "Hoch" in "Hochdeutsch* gefragt. Dass man in Süddeutschland Dialekt spricht, steht hier doch gar nicht zur Debatte.

Comment: @Takkat: Siehe die Klammerbemerkung in meinem ersten Kommentar.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Bei Hadumod Bußmann steht als 1. Sinn die Bezeichnung für die überregionale deutsche Hochsprache und als 2. Sinn das Deutsch südlich der Bennrather Linie. Generell ist es eine unglückliche Begriffswahl, aber der baden-württembergische Slogan "Wir können alles. Außer Hochdeutsch" führte an der Uni zu sehr viel Belustigung.

Answer (score 2):

Der Begriff »Hochdeutsch« hat zwei Bedeutungen:

### **Hochdeutsch als Gegensatz zu Niederdeutsch**

Niederdeutsch ist die Umgangssprache (also das im Alltag gesprochene Deutsch) in den nördlicheren Gebieten des deutschen Sprachraumes. Hochdeutsch bezeichnet das, was man im Süden spricht. Die Grenze bildet die ungefähre Linie Düsseldorf-Kassel-Leipzig-Cottbus. (Details wissen Google und Wikipedia.)

Die Silbe »Hoch« rührt also von der geographischen Lage her. In höheren Lagen spricht man Hochdeutsch, im Flachland Niederdeutsch.

### **Hochdeutsch als Gegensatz zu Dialekten**

Zu keiner Zeit, weder in der Vergangenheit, noch in der Gegenwart, gab/gibt es ein einheitliches Deutsch. Deutsch bestand immer schon aus einer Vielzahl verschiedener Dialekte, und es gab über die Jahrhunderte hinweg viele Versuche, diese Dialekte zu vereinheitlichen.

Hochdeutsch ist der aktuelle Versuch, einen einheitlichen Standard der deutschen Sprache zu schaffen. Hochdeutsch ist also als gehobenes Deutsch zu verstehen. Ein Synonym dafür ist »Standarddeutsch«.

Vor allem in Deutschland (und dem nicht-deutschsprachigen Ausland) hat sich aber noch nicht flächendeckend rumgesprochen, dass es drei verschieden Varianten des standardisierten Hochdeutsch gibt, weil die Staaten Schweiz, Österreich und Deutschland drei sehr ähnliche, aber nicht genau gleiche Standardisierungen der deutschen Sprache hervorgebracht haben, die auch von der jeweils dort ansässigen Presse gebraucht werden. Die Unterschiede zwischen diesen drei Standards liefern Stoff für ganze Regale voll Fachliteratur.

Answer (score 1):

Ich vermute, dass außer mir viele andere Kinder während ihrer Schulzeit zu hören bekamen

> Sprich bitte richtiges (oder auch vernünftiges) Hochdeutsch!

Da ich in einer Stadt aufgewachsen bin, in der nur noch die wenigsten Kinder den lokalen Dialekt sprechen konnten, bin ich mir ziemlich sicher, dass damit die Unterscheidung zwischen der Umgangssprache und den Erwartungen der Schule gemeint ist.

Von daher denke ich bei Hochdeutsch zunächst eher an kultiviert, wohlerzogen und gebildet.

Comment: ja, so sehen es wohl die meisten Menschen. Jedoch: Warum heißt es *Hoch*deutsch?

Comment: Beantwortet die Frage doch überhaupt nicht. Hier wird die Bedeutung des Wortes beschrieben statt die Herkunft des Begriffs hoch in Hochdeutsch.

Comment: So etwas passiert halt, wenn der Titel der Frage nicht völlig mit dem Text über einstimmt. Der Titel fragt eindeutig nach der Bedeutung und wenn jemand von einer Suchmaschine zu dieser Frage geleitet wird, dann ist es gut, wenn er auch zu diesem Aspekt hier eine Antwort findet.

Answer (score 1):

Der Begriff Hochdeutsch ist ursprünglich eine rein geografische Bezeichnung für zwei
Deutschvarianten. Im Norden, dem flachen Land sagt man Water wie in Waterkant, im Süden, dem höher gelegenen Land, sagt man Wasser. Die südliche Deutschvariante ist mit der Zeit zur Standardsprache geworden und hat sich in ganz Deutschland durchgesetzt. Man spricht in Hamburg genauso Hochdeutsch wie in München, wenn man auch regionale Färbungen hören kann.

Es wäre besser,heute von Standarddeutsch zu sprechen, denn es wird überall im deutschen Sprachraum gesprochen. Allerdings sind die Dialekte noch sehr lebendig und werden gepflegt. Bairische Dilalektliteratur in Prosa und Lyrik ist immens, und das gleiche gilt für Plattdeutsch, für das es allerhand Portale im Internet gibt. Siehe de.wikipedia Plattdeutsch.

Comment: Das Volk versteht unter dem Begriff Hochdeutsch nur das, was mit Standarddeutsch gemeint ist. Die geografische Bezeichnung sollte man vielleicht lieber ändern in Süd- und Norddeutsch...

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is as follows:

In the word 'hoch-deutsch'
the word 'hoch' (= 'hoh') means 'superior' or 'better', 
which is to say not only a german dialect.

Some examples:

> 'das hohe Lied von\vom\des ... singen' {geflügelt}.
>   Hochzeit (= 'hohe Zeit' = 'gute Zeit').
>   'Sie leben hoch!'.
>   'Herr Hochwürden'.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.